# Python: Drawing a rectangle around center coordinates given by user while using imported height and width

Tags: python, math, coordinates, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to figure this out all day. How to draw a rectangle around the x,y coordinates given for the center of the rectangle all the while using the Height and width given from the user. any help would be amazing.

```
import turtle


centerX = float(input("Enter the center x cordinates of the rectangle: "))
centerY = float(input("Enter the center y cordinates of the rectangle: "))
width = float(input("enter, width: "))
height = float(input("enter, height: "))


turtle.showturtle()

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(centerX,centerY)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.goto(-width/2,centerY)
turtle.goto(-width/2,height/2)
turtle.goto(width,height/2)
turtle.goto(width,-height)
turtle.goto(-width,-height)
turtle.goto(-width,height/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compute the coordinates of all four corners of your rectangle. If you know the center then it's easy to see that they are all of form (centerX +/-width/2, centerY +/- height/2). Go to the first corner with the pen up, and then go through all the corners in a certain order, for example clockwise.

For the future, it's probably helpful to remember that if you want a picture around a certain point (like your center), then you probably all the coordinates you move through will be relative to it, and so will include its value.

```
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(centerX-width/2,centerY-height/2)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.goto(centerX-width/2,centerY+height/2)
turtle.goto(centerX+width/2,centerY+height/2)
turtle.goto(centerX+width/2,centerY-height/2)
turtle.goto(centerX-width/2, centerY-height/2)
```

Comment: I ended up with this exact solution this morning thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Start at the middle, then turn and move:

```
import turtle
x, y = 0, 0
h, w = 60, 100
s = turtle.Screen()
turtle.penup()
# start at the center
turtle.goto(x,y)
# head east
turtle.setheading(0)
# go to the middle of the right side
turtle.forward(w / 2)
# turn south, put the pen down, start drawing
turtle.setheading(270)
turtle.pendown()
# southeast corner
turtle.forward(h / 2)
# southwest corner
turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.forward(w)
# northwest corner
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.forward(h)
# northeast corner
turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.forward(w)
# to the start
turtle.setheading(270)
turtle.forward(h / 2)
turtle.penup()
```

---

Or more concisely:

```
turtle.penup()
# start at the center
turtle.goto(x,y)
# head east
turtle.setheading(0)
# go to the middle of the right side
turtle.forward(w / 2)
# turn south, go to south east corner
turtle.setheading(270)
turtle.forward(h / 2)
#put the pen down, start drawing
turtle.pendown()
for heading, distance in zip((180, 90, 0, 270), (w, h, w, h)):
    turtle.setheading(heading)
    turtle.forward(distance)
turtle.penup()
```